# Get JSON from url error

Tags: android, json

I'm trying get a JSON from [this url](http://tcc-teste.aws.af.cm/api/get/aluno/1) using [this class](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/).

I'm using getJSONFromUrl like that:

```
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();//Instantiate class
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://tcc-teste.aws.af.cm/api/get/aluno/1");//using getJSNOFromUrl method
```

And I'm geting this error on logcat:

```
08-28 22:46:06.560: E/AndroidRuntime(905): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-28 22:46:06.560: E/AndroidRuntime(905): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.br.edu.unifoa/com.example.br.edu.unifoa.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-28 22:46:06.560: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
08-28 22:46:06.560: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-28 22:46:06.560: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-28 22:46:06.560: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-28 22:46:06.560: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-28 22:46:06.560: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-28 22:46:06.560: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
```

Comment: Just read the error, it says no network on main thread!?!?!?!, use AsynchTask or something else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to parse on UI Thread (Main thread) whihc is causing this error. Run an asynctask and do it. It wont crash then. Any networking or long running work should not be done on UI thread as it blocks it.

Comment: Happy to help :) .. it happened to most of us when we started :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this before you Parsing

```
public static int SDK_INT = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

if (SDK_INT >= 10) {
                    ThreadPolicy tp = ThreadPolicy.LAX;
                    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);
                }
```

add this permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: You can use async tasks also.but if you have small amount of data to parse it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

thank you brother but change like this
   public static int SDK_INT = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

```
{
    if (SDK_INT >= 10) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy tp = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.LAX;
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer does not seem to match the query. Can you please explain why this answer solves the question, if they match?